# Type hints with forward references

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, annotations

I'm implementing a tree like this

```
class A:
    children: List[A]
```

However in PyCharm I get `Unresolved reference 'A'` . Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a string:

```
class A:
    children: List['A']
```

This is the documentation for [Forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)